# Auto scroll down web browser in C# winforms programmatically

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

I need to autoscroll webbrowser automatically with code.

I tried with this function but it didn't work:

```
   private void ScrollbrowserToTheend(WebBrowser br)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i += 10000)
            {
                br.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, i);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `DocumentCompleted` event:

```
private void myWebBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    myWebBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, myWebBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Height);
}
```